# Add Rules in Jena SDB

Tags: java, sparql, jena

I have designed a block to do queries for Jena SDB in my Java class, but I don't know how can I add my rules, where it's in a file in My class. I add the code.

```
String jdbcURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ontology";
    System.out.println("##### GETUSERSTYPE #####");
     JDBC.loadDriverMySQL();
    // Setup - make the JDBC connection and read the store description once.
    Connection jdbc = makeConnection(jdbcURL) ;

    // Make a store description without any connection information.
    StoreDesc storeDesc = new StoreDesc(LayoutType.LayoutTripleNodesHash,DatabaseType.MySQL) ;

    SDBConnection conn = new SDBConnection(jdbc) ;

    Store store = StoreFactory.create(storeDesc, conn) ;

    Dataset ds = DatasetStore.create(store) ;

    QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, ds) ;
```

Comment: Try looking in the Jena documentation at http://jena.apache.org/ -- specifically, the inference documentation and the assembler documentation.  Note SDB is deprecated unless you really must use an SQL database - TDB is a better choice.

Comment: I'm using an SQL database, and I could resolve my problem importing the model from the dataset loaded from database. Thank you.